# In host machine, cannot connect webserver, vagrant

Tags: vagrant, ubuntu-14.10

I am running ubuntu 14.10 through vagrant

host machine is windows 8.1

In host machine (windows 8.1),

1. I can send ICMP message to guest:ubuntu
2. I can connect ssh to guest:ubuntu, for portforwarding - In windows, localhost:2222
3. But only cannot connect to webserver of ubuntu, localhost:3000 or 4000 or anyport
   just showed `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

of course, portforwarding is done

actually, In ubuntu, I can connect webserver for

```
lynx localhost:3000
```

but in windows, I can't connect only webserver.
ssh, icmp are works. 
Really, I can't understand why it doesn't work.
sombody help me

Comment: show me the part how you do portforwarding in `Vagrantfile`. I will recommend to set private IP, then you needn't worry about the port forwarding.

Comment: @BMW I found the solution from other post. Thank you for your favor

Comment: Great, if you fix your own problem, yo'd better to make conclusion and answer your own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution is running with code below when start server.

```
rails s -b 0.0.0.0
```

I found this soulution from other post about same problem The answerer said 'You'll want to make sure that the server is bound to 0.0.0.0 so that all interfaces can access it."

I hope this post help people who meet with the same problem :)